# Spark view engine - why there is no VS integration in version 1.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I downloaded Spark 1.1 release from http://sparkviewengine.codeplex.com/releases/view/27601 and cannot find the msi package for Visual Studio integration promised in docs.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: R0MANARMY, for any VS :) There is neither

Answer (score 2):

For VS2008 support, I'm not sure why it's not included in the latest downloads on codeplex, but you can still get the .msi from the download on [spark downloads page.](http://sparkviewengine.com/download)

For VS2010, the answer is a [little bit more complicated](http://groups.google.com/group/spark-dev/browse_thread/thread/ffb6da958c169335).  The short version though is that the visual studio editor changed [drastically in VS2010](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Continuum/WPF-Design-Surface-Improvements-in-Visual-Studio-2010/) and the way the old plug-in was providing intellisence is no longer appropriate.

Comment: But Spark downloads page says that "Download assets have been relocated" and points to codeplex, where I cannot find any msi package. Thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: The MSI was never available as a standalone download, it was included in the .zip download.  There's this (http://sparkviewengine.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=5763) issue on codeplex so maybe 2008 integration doesn't work, or maybe it was just an oversight.

Comment: I used SparkVsIntegration-1.0.39935.0-release.msi  from an earlier package for 1.1 and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the msi installed and working from 1.0.39935.0 with 1.1. I had to close and re-open VS and a few pages.